# Regex to Cisco Interface

Tags: linux, awk, cisco

I would like to know if have some `sed`, `grep` or `awk` regex to parse Cisco interface section and exclude if interface is down (shutdown), like example below.

Example:

```
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.16.0.1 255.255.255.224
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 ip address 10.17.0.1 255.255.255.224
 shutdown
!
```

I'm using `sed` regex below to parse interface section:

```
sed -n -e '/^interface/,/^!/p' file.txt
```

But the regex above, parse all interface and not exclude interface down.

Comment: FYI, you asked for shell tools; however, [ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse) is a python module which specializes in handling these kind of tasks.  If you do a lot of this, it may be worth your while to consider using a library which is built for parsing cisco configs.

Answer (score 1):

#### awk

With GNU awk or mawk you could do it like this:

```
awk -v RS='!\n' '!/shutdown/'
```

Output:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.16.0.1 255.255.255.224
```

You could make the match more precise if you only look for shutdown in the third line:

```
awk -v RS='!\n' -v FS='\n +' '$3 !~ /shutdown/'
```

#### sed

You can of course also use sed, but it is more complicated.

One approach is the one you've started with, but collect the whole record in hold space before printing anything. This works with GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^interface/,/^!/ H; 1b; /^!/ { z; x; s/^\n//g; /shutdown/!p }'
```

Comment: @user32634: I'm glad it helped you. The way to say thanks around here is by up-voting useful answers and accepting the most useful answer.